# Chrome extension - how can background.js create variables and functions that persist on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to inject some JS on a web page using a chrome extension. Since I want to enable it only on click and not every time I visit the page, I have the following manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Assistant",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
        "css": ["css/style.css"],
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon.png",
    "default_title": "Assistant"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": ["css/style.css"]
}
```

In background.js, I load the scripts with this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "js/jquery.min.js" }, function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "js/script.js" });
    });

});
```

Now on script.js I have the following line:

```
var a = "testing";
window.b = "testing";
alert("testing");
```

When I click the button, the browser immediately displays an alert for "testing", meaning it ran the code correctly. But, when I go to the console and try to access a or window.b, both are undefined.

Are these variables being sandboxed somehow? How to make it available for page scripts?

Comment: I think it executes in backgrounds, not in content script. So `window.b` exists in backgrounds enviroment, while `console.log` you call in content enviroment. Try click _inspect views: background.page_ on `chrome://extensions/` page and call `window.b` in that console. It will show "testing".

Comment: how can I call them in the content environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert code into the page context using a content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script)

Comment: Take a look at this:
https://gist.github.com/naholyr/8657eb77e198e1b49c1d